# A rigorous proof of Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, functions

I faced several proofs of Cauchy-Riemann theorem :

**Issue**

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{C} $ holomorphic.

$$ u : (x,y)\to \Re(f)(x+iy)$$
$$ v : (x,y)\to \Im(f)(x+iy)$$

Then:

$$ \begin{cases}
\partial_1u=\partial_2v\\
\partial_2u=-\partial_1 v
\end{cases} $$

But I always found a lack of rigour related to the following expression :

" $ f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y) $ "

The issues comes from treating $f$ as a function of ${\mathbb{R}^2}^{\mathbb{R}^2}$ in nebulously way instead of treating it as a function of $ \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{C}$ . We also find proof like [this.](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m300/cauchyRiemann.pdf) But it doesn't deal in terms of function in the limit but in decomposition. *By doing like this we are mixing up the 2 kinds of functions described above.*

**Question**

I thought we could define 
$$ \phi : (x,y)\to x+iy$$
Then
$$ F:(x,y)\to f[\phi(x,y)]$$
So we have :

$$ F :(x,y) \to u(x,y)+iv(x,y)= \Re(f)(x+iy)+\Im(f)(x+iy)$$

How could we clearly show the theorem by properly introduce coherent functions ? I mean we can't say $ f: z \to f(x+iy)$ it makes non sense in terms of function.

*Which functions could we introduce to have a natural proof **involving limits of functions*** ?
 And without using the expression mixing $x,y$ even if it is understandable (but unprecise and muffled) in that way.

Thanks , I hope I'm precise enough.

Comment: It is impossible to even state the Cauchy-Riemann equations without considering $\Bbb R^2$ as a representation of $\Bbb C$ since the equations are about the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

There is a canonical way of identifying functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ with functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, if $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $(x, y) \rightarrow (u(x,y), v(x,y))$, you can view $f$ as a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ by the map $a + bi \rightarrow u(a, b) + iv(a, b).$ It can be shown that this gives a one-to-one correspondence between functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, and that this correspondence is preserved under scaling and addition. Hence, even if these different types of functions are in play, as long as the identification is properly made nothing is being "mixed up." This identification is probably being done under the covers without mention in the proofs that you have referenced.

Comment: Thanks ! Yet, I know this canonical isomorphism defined by $$  \Psi : f\in \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{C} \to (\Re(f),\Im(f)) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}^{\mathbb{R}^2}$$ . I not sufficient to mix up functions  **in equalities**

Comment: If the issue here is that the equals sign is used when this identification is, I think the thing to do is to expand the proof you're looking at with words to explicitly mention when you go between the two representations to see for yourself that the ideas shown in the steps taken are valid.

Comment: You mention a proper identification and it will be pleasant to be precised if you manage to do it.

Comment: I think that this is the best answer because of how concise and to the point it is. I would also add that, without going into further details concerning isomorphisms between fields, one may define $\Bbb C$ to  be exactly $ \Bbb R^2 $ and then just define the usual operations on there: in this way $f(z)=f(x,y)$ (I.e. they are exactly the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy Riemann equations **inherently** involve real and imaginary parts

- in the codomain (that's $u$ and $v$)
- in the domain as well (since you have partial derivatives).

So there is absolutely no way to avoid having them in the proof.

Comment: It isn't a matter of avoding using real and imaginary parts by clearly defining the limits in terms of functions . Look at the hyperlink I mentionned , we here are mixing up $z$  
 arguments functions and $(x,y)$ argument functions

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my question like this :

As usual define:

$$u:(x,y)\to \Re(f)(x+iy)$$
$$v:(x,y) \to \Im(f)(x+iy) $$

Then we will write $f$ without any $(x,y)$ , **because we will write it in terms of function(s)**

$$ f : z\to u(\Re(z),\Im(z)) +iv(\Re(z),\Im(z)) $$

In other words :

$$f=u(\Re({I_d}_\mathbb{C}),\Im({I_d}_\mathbb{C}))+iv(\Re({I_d}_\mathbb{C}),\Im({I_d}_\mathbb{C})) $$

So it is rigorous to talk about our usual proof etc.

Let $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ .

$$ \forall h \in \mathbb{C}^*, \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}= \frac{[ u(\Re(z+h),\Im(z+h))- u(\Re(z),\Im(z))] +i[v(\Re(z+h),\Im(z+h))-v(\Re(z),\Im(z))]}{h} $$

By composition of holomorphic functions :

$$u(\Re({I_d}_\mathbb{C}),\Im({I_d}_\mathbb{C})) $$
$$v(\Re({I_d}_\mathbb{C}),\Im({I_d}_\mathbb{C}))$$

are holomorphic.

And we have $u$ and $v$ in  $\mathcal{C} ^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ because of the holomorphy of $f$ and the linearity of $\Re$.

Now I'm questionning on the meaning of the differentiation of ( for instance)
 $$u(\Re({I_d}_\mathbb{C}),\Im({I_d}_\mathbb{C})) $$

Thanks